# I want to find specific class prefix

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to change the name of a specific class. I tried several ways but I'm still failing.

`var tdObj = $ ("div.event-list-item") .parents (). addClass ("disable");`

Seems to be a problem.

```
function endTimeCheck() {
        $("span[name='betStatus']" ).each( function(){
            var play_timestamp = parseInt( $( this ).attr( "timestamp" ) ); 
            var countdown = play_timestamp - timestamp - 32700; 
            if( countdown <= 0 ) 
            {
                if ($( this ).css("color") != "red") { 
                    $( this ).css( "color", "red" ).text( "Close" ); 

                // An error occurs.                 
                    var tdObj = $( "div.event-list-item" ).parents().addClass("disable");
                // An error occurs.

                }
            }
```

HTML is: Line 6 : I want to change the div class name if the condition is correct.

```
before: <div class="event-list-item "> 
after: <div class="event-list-item disable">
```

---

```
<div class="bet_list">
    <div class="event-list-date">
        <img src="/img/country/icon_ITA D1.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;ITA D1
    </div>
    <div class="event-list">
        <div class="event-list-item ">
            <div class="event-list-table">
                <div class="event-list-row" data-eventid="430046,2.30,3.20,3.30">
                    <div class="elc elc-time">
                        10-22 03:45
                    </div>
                    <div class="elc bet-trigger" id="430046_1">CFC
                        <div class="elc-odds"><span class="o">2.30</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="elc bet-trigger elc--draw" id="430046_0">
                        <div class="elc-odds"><span class="o">3.20</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="elc bet-trigger elc--right" id="430046_2">
                        FC 1909
                        <div class="elc-odds"><span class="o">3.30</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="elc elc-more">
                        <div class="elc-more-count" data-id="2588380">
                            <span name="betStatus" timestamp="1508643900" style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">Close</span>&nbsp;&nbsp; +2
                        </div>
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have type for parentS: `https://api.jquery.com/parent/` correct variant in singular form.

Comment: or may be you dont need parents at all. Could you create a jsfiddle for your case ?

Comment: if you want the result to be `<div class="event-list-item disable">` then `$( "div.event-list-item" ).parents().addClass("disable");` is wrong, because it will add the class `disabled` to the parent of `<div class="event-list-item">`. instead, you could just do `$( "div.event-list-item" ).addClass("disable");`

Comment: If you need the class `disabled` added to `.event-list-item` why are you using `.parents()`? Wouldn't you want to use `$("span[name='betStatus']").parents()...` or `$(this).parents()...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off all i don't know where you want to go with this, for things that include html, css, jquery try to use SO's snippet so we could be more helpfull.
that beeing said, i noticed that you trying to test an element by it's color, and as far as i know, this is not a good way to go about it, why? because the major browsers will always return the  color in rgb or rgba format, what you did could work with older browsers, what i suggest you to do is to take take that style and wrap it in css class, and check for the existence of the css class, again i don't know what you trying to do, so i just call it *.closed*

```js
function endTimeCheck() {

      $("span[name='betStatus']").each(function() {
       var $span = $(this);
          var play_timestamp = parseInt( $span.attr( "timestamp" ) ); 

          var timestamp = 1508643900; // i presume you declared this somewhere in your script
          var countdown = (play_timestamp - timestamp) - 32700; 

          if( countdown <= 0 ) {

           if (! $span.hasClass('closed')) {

                  $span.css("color", "red").text( "Close" ); 
                
                  var tdObj = $span.parents('.event-list-item').addClass("disable");
           }
          }
      });
  }

  endTimeCheck();
```

```css
.closed {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>Your title here</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="bet_list">
     <div class="event-list-date">
         
     </div>
     <div class="event-list">
         <div class="event-list-item ">
             <div class="event-list-table">
                 <div class="event-list-row" data-eventid="430046,2.30,3.20,3.30">
                     <div class="elc elc-time">
                         10-22 03:45
                     </div>
                     <div class="elc bet-trigger" id="430046_1">CFC
                         <div class="elc-odds"><span class="o">2.30</span>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="elc bet-trigger elc--draw" id="430046_0">
                         <div class="elc-odds"><span class="o">3.20</span></div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="elc bet-trigger elc--right" id="430046_2">
                         FC 1909
                         <div class="elc-odds"><span class="o">3.30</span></div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="elc elc-more">
                         <div class="elc-more-count" data-id="2588380">
                             <span name="betStatus" timestamp="1508643900" class="closed">Close</span>&nbsp;&nbsp; +2
                         </div>
                         <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
  
  </body>
</html>
```